# how to concatenate Date & Year into one column sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have Date in one column & year in column and i need to concatenate and get the answer as Jan-2017 and that should be in actual Month oder

Comment: add some data sample and specify data types

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT(column1, ',', column2) AS Date,
      FROM   table;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. I assume your both column data types are DateTime or Date. Try the following:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(DATENAME(month, YourMonthColumn), 0,4), '-', Year(YourYearColumn))
FROM YourTableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server 2008 compatible: (no `concat()` and no `format()`)

Using a [**`convert()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)) style of 106 (or 113), and just taking the `mon yyyy` part, and replacing the `' '` with `'-'`, 

 and using dates truncated to the month, so we can group and order by it using `dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [Date] ),0)`:

```
select MonthYear = replace(stuff(convert(varchar(12)
       ,dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [Date]), 0)
       ,106),1,3,''),' ','-')
       , Days = count(*)
from dates
group by dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [Date]), 0)
order by dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [Date]), 0)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DFF74396

returns:

```
+-----------+------+
| MonthYear | Days |
+-----------+------+
| Dec-2016  |   31 |
| Jan-2017  |   31 |
| Feb-2017  |   28 |
| Mar-2017  |   10 |
+-----------+------+
```

---

Alternate using [**`datename(month,date)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) for the month and concatenating the year:

```
select MonthYear = left(datename(month,dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [Date]), 0)),3)
       + '-'
       + convert(char(4),year(dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [Date]), 0)))
       , Days = count(*)
from dates
group by dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [Date]), 0)
order by dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [Date]), 0)
```